Gap between Rigid Foam Boards and Wall Framing (About 2 inches)
I am currently finishing my basement. I will be putting 1" rigid foam on the concrete wall of my basement and will have wall framing about 2 inches away from it. Is there a code or best practice that requires the framing wall to be within specific distance from the rigid foams?
Below is a sketch to further illustrate the point.

Thank you!

Building regulations will vary from region to region, where is it the property in question?

Mostly there's self-interest in not losing too much interior space to unusable "waste" space. That and no wood to rot are why "basement finishing systems" which are more-or-less foamboard with a fire-rated interior finish side exist. A 2" gap on 6 linear feet of wall costs you a square foot of floor space.
